# Yii how to set email layout from theme

Tags: php, yii

I'm using **Yii 1.1**

I want to set up a theme for my application , and its worked well for my application using 
`Yii::app()->theme    = 'user-theme'`;

but its not working for **email** layout its still reading from deafult layout inside my application.

i tried in side my email function to set layout path using

```
$mail->setLayoutPath(Yii::app()->theme->basePath.'.views.layouts');
```

but it return this error

```
View "/xx/xx/user-theme.views.layouts.mail" does not exist!
```

how to configure it to read email layout from **theme**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding layout path to mail config inside **/config/mail.php**

```
'layoutPath'=>'webroot.themes.user-theme.views.layouts',
'savePath' => 'webroot.assets.mail',
```

thanks